# How to store and JSON-serialize Map of Objects AND SObjects

Tags: apex, json, map, collection

This question is an extension to [Write a generic JSON-serializable Parameters class without hitting “Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object”](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12255/write-a-generic-json-serializable-parameters-class-without-hitting-apex-type-un) where I learned how to serialize a Map to and from JSON.

My problem now is, that I also want to store SObjects as map values and always get a

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type
>   MAP<String,ANY> to SOBJECT:Account

in the last line of this snippet:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new Map<String, Object>();
Account acme = new Account(Name = 'Acme Corp.');
insert acme;
parameters.put('SObject', acme);
String serialized = JSON.serialize(parameters);
parameters = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(serialized);
Account restoredAcme = (Account) parameters.get('SObject');
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this instead of your last line of code:

```
String jsonstr = (String)JSON.serialize(parameters.get('SObject'));
SObject restoredAcme = (Account)JSON.deserialize(jsonstr, Account.class);
```

The problem with what you're currently trying to do is that you're essentially trying to cast a Map to an Account - which as you've seen, you cannot do.

As a workaround, you can serialize the Map to String and then deserialize that String to an Account.

Comment: That basically means you cannot serialize/deserialize a map with Objects AND SObjects to JSON, right?! So to store an SObject in a Map<String, Object> I first have to serialize it to a String, store it, deserialize as String and the deserialize with a concrete Type.

Comment: So the explanation is that the first deserialize creates a map for the Object (which sObject type basically is, a bunch of key-value entries) and then you need to remap it to the proper sObject. Makes sense actually.

Comment: Btw, to make it generic, you can deserialize the jsonstr to sobject.class and then cast somewhere outside.

Comment: I think you can serialize/deserialize a map with Objects AND SObjects - you just need to know the type to deserialize as (remember a Map<String,Object> is not an SObject hence the serialization to string first). Maybe you can expand on your question if there is more too it?

Answer (score 3):

If you change your code to the code below the deserialize step will create a Map instance. The JSON parser cannot deserialize to a common object, it does understand how to construct an SObject.

Regards,

Leon

```
Map<String, SObject> parameters = new Map<String, SObject>();
Account acme = new Account(Name = 'Acme Corp.');
insert acme;
parameters.put('SObject', acme);
String serialized = JSON.serialize(parameters);
parameters = (Map<String, SObject>) JSON.deserialize(serialized, Map<String, SObject>.class);
Account restoredAcme = (Account) parameters.get('SObject');
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Restored acme name: ' + restoredAcme.name );
```