# JSON.serialize Url object throwing System.JSONException

Tags: apex, json, serialization

I'm getting the following JSONException when JSON serializing a Map of generic Objects which contains a Url object deeply nested within.

```
System.JSONException: Type unsupported in JSON: common.apex.methods.ApexUrl$URIImpl
```

It looks like Apex doesn't support JSON serializing the Url class because I was able to replicate the error in Anonymous Apex simply with `JSON.serialize(new Url('https://www.google.com'));`.

What would be the best way to serialize my object without having to refactor my Url properties to String? For some context, I'm serializing [the Map described in this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12255/write-a-generic-json-serializable-parameters-class-without-hitting-apex-type-un).

Comment: Can you add sample JSON?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I'm trying to serialize a Url object to JSON, so I don't have any sample JSON to give.

Comment: @KevinVizcarra hes talking about the object you're trying to serialize

Comment: You're going to have to change the properties to `String`. Why do you want to leave them as `URL`? You seem to be having a bit of an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: I tried debugging the URL's toString method. It looks like that object was not designed to be serialised.  If you force it to serialize it will form a malformed JSON.


.----->
System.debug(JSON.serialize(new Url('https://www.google.com').toString()));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do *some* refactoring, but this is a pretty clean solution:

```
public class DataHandler {
    public string urlAsString { get; set; }
    public transient Url urlAsUrl { get { return new Url(urlAsString); } set { urlAsString = value.toExternalForm(); }}
}
DataHandler x = new DataHandler();
x.urlAsUrl = new Url('https://www.google.com');
System.debug(JSON.serialize(x));
```

The "transient" bit keeps JSON.serialize from handling the Url data, but it will serialize the string just fine.